# Tree splitting(extracting) algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm, tree

In the simplest case I have two trees (directed graphs), each tree node has an unique id and can have multiple children, where all leafs of the second tree are contained in the leafs of the first one. Based on the leafs I want to split the first tree into two trees in such way that new first tree will not contain any of the leafs of the original second tree and new second tree will contain all leafs of original second tree. The trick is also that if all children of a node will be moved to new second tree then the node itself should also be moved.

For example for such two trees as an input:

- 1 (root of first tree)

  - 11

    - 111

      - 1111

        - 11111
        - 11112
      - 1112

        - 11121
        - 11122
    - 112

      - 11201
      - 11202
  - 12

    - 121

      - 12101
      - 12102
    - 122

      - 12201
      - 12202
- 2 (root of second tree)

  - 21

    - 211

      - 2111

        - 11112
    - 212

      - 11201
      - 11202

I would like to get as a result two new trees such that:

- 1 (root of new first tree)

  - 11

    - 111

      - 1111

        - 11111
      - 1112

        - 11121
        - 11122
  - 12

    - 121

      - 12101
      - 12102
    - 122

      - 12201
      - 12202
- 2 (root of new second tree)

  - 21

    - 211

      - 2111

        - 11112
    - 112 (node copied from original first tree cause all its children where copied)

      - 11201
      - 11202

What would be the best approach (algorithm) to achieve this?

Removing the nodes from first tree is simple, but I have problem how to construct second tree reusing nodes from first one where suitable.

I'm trying to implement this splitting in Java version 1.7 (I cannot use 1.8).

#### Edit

I was able to come up with one solution, more detail in my answer below, but if someone will provide I better one I will be also happy :)

Comment: You seem to have in mind a specific implementation in a certain programming language. We need to know which one (procedural, with pointers, etc.), otherwise we won't be able to help, because the trivial answer to your question would be: you already have tree 2.

Comment: How do you know that node 112 ends up a child of node 21? What if there were nodes 22 and 23 on this level, why not add to any of them?

Comment: @Vroomfondel I'm implementing this in Java 1.6, added link to a sample code on BitBucket.

Comment: @fafl In original tree there was a node 212 which has same children as 112, that is why this node should be replaced, but it's parent stays the same.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with a solution to my problem, maybe it will be of any use to somebody. My algorithm is as follows:

1. Lets call the first original tree a source tree and second original tree a mask tree.
2. Convert the tree into a list of leaves with its parents from all original trees.
3. Iterate over the list of leaves and rebuild the trees from the leaf parents.

   - the parents from mask tree have bigger priority thet the parents from source tree
   - for the mask tree parents register the source tree parents as possible replacements
4. Iterate over the possible replacements and if the replacement was not used in any tree, then replace with it the node.

Not sure if I made it clear enough or not. If not check the implamantation that is available on BitBucket [TreeSplitter](https://bitbucket.org/MJar13/treesplitter).

This solution might be not optimal, so if you have a better approach post it as an answer.